# Do i need for every instance of redis a new connection?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Can I use only one static connection?

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");

 IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase(0);
 IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase(1);
 IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase(2);
```

Comment: Why don't you just try the posted code? If you try it, you'll see that it works.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/docs/Basics.md):

> The central object in StackExchange.Redis is the ConnectionMultiplexer class in the StackExchange.Redis namespace; this is the object that hides away the details of multiple servers. Because the ConnectionMultiplexer does a lot, **it is designed to be shared and reused** between callers. You should not create a ConnectionMultiplexer per operation. It is fully thread-safe and ready for this usage.